# InfoPath Form: How to redirect to URL with parameters after pressing a button?

Tags: infopath, redirect

Solution with "?Source=..." is not what i need, because i want to pass parameter to page. This parameter is returned by some function after pressing a button on the form.

For example: I have a form with some text fields and submit button, custom code on button click event, which creates new item in sharepoint list. I want to redirect to webpart page and send ID of the new item to it.